# Can't upgrade or install programs (Unmet dependencies Error(1)) Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies, dpkg

As I see my problem is similar to this one
[libc6 dependency mismatch in Debian 9.12 stretch](https://serverfault.com/questions/1004890/libc6-dependency-mismatch-in-debian-9-12-stretch/1004951#1004951).
Please,advice a solution for my distribution

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsystemd0:i386 libudev1:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6 libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 libc6:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 461 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5 287 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2 048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 258230 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:i386 (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temp
orarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:amd64 (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temp
orarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.31-0ubuntu9.2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: looks like you have at least this problem:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/136881/debconf-dbdriver-config-config-dat-is-locked-by-another-process-resource-t
once you have fixed that try installing again, might work already.

Comment: shortfix (but maybe dangerous) check for running apt, dpkg processes, if not you may have to decide try reboot and run apt install which will mostly not work or delete the lock file and run then the apt install this time it may run

Comment: Don't find similarity. Output in my case:
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                     root       7573 F.... frontend

Why should I kill that. Please, explain

Comment: The similarity is that you have another process ruining and holding the lock on `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` which prevents you from running `apt` commands.

Comment: Thank you! That worker out